# Create a Post_category for a Post a choose my post with collection post_category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, controller

I created a post_category table to add a category to specifics posts.

For example I created post_categories as Countries, Like Japan or China. And I want to create post which are come from culture or mode from countries like Japan or China. I focused only on post_categories as countries for now and below is the code I did.

I created this `PostCategory`, here are the migration and model

```
 create_table "post_categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

class PostCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy

  NAMES = ["Japon", "Chine", "Corée du Sud", "Moyen Orient", "Indien"]
  validates :name, inclusion: { in: PostCategory::NAMES, allow_nil: false }
end
```

And I created a `Post` with the `PostCategory` foreign key, here are the migration and model

```
  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "cover"
    t.string   "subtitle"
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "introduction"
    t.text     "body"
    t.text     "conclusion"
    t.string   "tag"
    t.string   "source"
    t.string   "link"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
    t.integer  "post_category_id"
  end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  belongs_to :post_category, dependent: :destroy

  TAGS = ["Design", "Mode", "Tendance", "Life-Style", "Tradition", "Gastronomie", "Insolite", "Technologie"]
  validates :tag, inclusion: { in: Post::TAGS, allow_nil: false }

  mount_uploader :cover, ImageUploader
end
```

I want to create a category with a simple form collection and I want i will be displayed on the `post show#view`

Here is the `post_categories controller`

```
class PostCategoriesController < ApplicationController
   # before_action :set_post_category, only: [:show, :new, :create, :destroy]

  def show
    @post_category = PostCategory.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @post_categories = PostCategory.all
  end

  def create
    @post_category = post_categories.new(post_category_params)
    if @post_category.save
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render 'post_categories/show'
    end
  end

  def new
    @post_category = PostCategory.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update

  end

  def destroy
    @post_category = PostCategory.find(params[:id])
    @post_category.destroy
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end

  private

  # def set_post
  #   @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  # end

   def find_post_category
    @post_category = PostCategory.find(params[:id])
  end

  def post_category_params
    params.require(:post_category).permit(:name, :description)
  end
end
```

And here is the `posts controller`

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show
    # @alert_message = "Vous lisez #{@post.title}"
  end

  def new
    # if current_user and current_user.admin?
      @post = Post.new
    # else
    #   redirect_to posts_path
    # end
  end

  def create
    # if current_user and current_user.admin?
     @post = @post_category.posts.new(post_params)
      #@post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)
      if @post.save
        redirect_to @post
      else
        render :new
      end
    # else
    #   render 'shared/404.html.erb'
    # end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @post.update(post_params)
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to :back
  end

  private

  # def find_post
  #   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  # end

  def set_post_category
    @post_category = PostCategory.find(params[:post_category_id])
  end

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :subtitle, :introduction, :body, :cover, :tag, :post_category_id)

  end
end
```

I don't know what views could I do create and how calling the `post new#view` because I configured my routes like that, and I need a `post_category_id`.

```
resources :post_categories do
    resources :posts
  end
```

That's I have to use this following `path`

```
 post_category_posts GET      /post_categories/:post_category_id/posts(.:format)          posts#index
                              POST     /post_categories/:post_category_id/posts(.:format)          posts#create
       new_post_category_post GET      /post_categories/:post_category_id/posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
      edit_post_category_post GET      /post_categories/:post_category_id/posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
           post_category_post GET      /post_categories/:post_category_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
                              PATCH    /post_categories/:post_category_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
                              PUT      /post_categories/:post_category_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
                              DELETE   /post_categories/:post_category_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy
              post_categories GET      /post_categories(.:format)                                  post_categories#index
                              POST     /post_categories(.:format)                                  post_categories#create
            new_post_category GET      /post_categories/new(.:format)                              post_categories#new
           edit_post_category GET      /post_categories/:id/edit(.:format)                         post_categories#edit
                post_category GET      /post_categories/:id(.:format)                              post_categories#show
                              PATCH    /post_categories/:id(.:format)                              post_categories#update
                              PUT      /post_categories/:id(.:format)                              post_categories#update
                              DELETE   /post_categories/:id(.:format)                              post_categories#destroy
```

I want to add the category on my show#view post and create a multisearch access to find posts added to a specific category. Thank you for your help

Comment: I think the sentence just before your routes extract is the key part of your question but it doesn't make any sense to me - could you reword it?

Comment: @FrederickCheung Yes I want to call post_category in my post show#view and create a search bar to fid post with this category

Answer (score 0):

The way you have setup your relations since has a very big flaw - a post can only belong to a single category since the id is stored on the posts table.

Instead you would commonly use a many to many relationship:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories, :categories
  has_many :post_categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :posts, through: :categories
end

class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :category
  validates_uniqueness_of :category_id, scope: :post_id
end
```

Here the `categorizations` table acts as a join table which links `Post` and `Category` - A post can have any number of categories and vice versa.

---

ADDED:

To create the join model and a migration to create table you would do:

```
rails g model Categorization post:belongs_to category:belongs_to
```

Using belongs to in the generator by default creates foreign keys for `post_id` and `category_id`.

You might want to add a compound uniqueness constraint in the migration as well.

```
def change 
  # ...
  add_index(:categorizations, [:post_id, :category_id], unique: true)
end
```

---

Your on the right track with your `CategoriesController` but I would not use a nested route to create posts. Instead you might want to just use a plain old rails controller and let the user select categories via check boxes:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :category_ids, Category.all, :id, : name %>
<% end %>
```

You would then add the `category_ids` param to the whitelist:

```
  def post_params
    params.require(:post)
          .permit(:title, :subtitle, :introduction, 
                  :body, :cover, :tag, category_ids: []
                 )

  end
```

The weird `category_ids: []` syntax is because we want to allow an array of scalar values.

Querying for posts from a category by id can be done like so:

```
Post.joins(:categories).where(category: 1)
```

You can even select multiple categories by passing an array:

```
Post.joins(:categories).where(category: [1, 2, 3])
```

To hook this together from the view you would use a link (for a single category) or a form (yes forms can be used for GET) with checkboxes or selects.

Dealing with textual input is a bit trickier. A naive implementation would be:

```
Post.joins(:categories).where(category: { name: params[:search_query] })
```

However the user input would have to match exactly. There are several gems that provide search features to active record. However I would wait with the feature until you have a bit more experience as it can be tricky to implement.

See:

- [Rails guides: The has_many :through Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)
- [Rails guides: Strong Parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters)
- [Rails api: collection_check_boxes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes)

Comment: do I create a Category foreign key for Posts

Comment: No the foreign keys are on the ´categorizations´ table.

Comment: I change my strategy could we talk about my code on chat? I need an external view.